# To redirect output to log file and also accept user input in same batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sqlplus

I am trying to write a batch script to run sql files on the database.
I want the script to put the results of the sql query execution into a log file (using something like >> SQl_LOGS.txt).That works fine but I want to get user input if
he/she wants to continue to execute the next SQl query or not.

Everything , even the pause is redirecting to the log file and hence
I am not able to provide any input on the console.

The subroutine which is called inside a for loop:

```
:ProcessQuery


(
echo WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1 
echo WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 1 
echo @%query% XXuser            // This should be sent top a log file

)  | sqlplus XXuser/XXpwdr@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=XX.XX.XX.XX)(Port=XXXX))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XXXX))) 


echo error level is : %ERRORLEVEL%

IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 ( 
   ECHO WARNING : QUERY %query% EXECUTION ERROR !   // these 3 lines should come up in the
                                                    // console      
   echo PLEASE FIX THE ERROR AND THEN HIT ENTER. 
   pause                        

) ELSE (
   echo %str% %query%
   ECHO  INFO : QUERY %query% EXECUTION SUCCESSFUL ! 
)
```

Can the same batch script output to a log file and also get user input from console?
is there a way I can achieve this ?

Comment: Is that whole subroutine redirected to log? If yes, use `echo This goes to the console >con:`

Comment: This worked great !! thank you very much!!1 I cracked my head for like 5 days for this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only certain parts of your script to be logged, just use >> SQL_LOGS.txt on those specific lines in your script (rather than using it on your call to the script).

As for prompting the user for a specific response, give this article a quick read: http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1154761&seqNum=12

EDIT - 
here's a batch script inspired by the above link that should help exemplify your goal.

```
@echo off
echo This is an example of accepting user input and writing some output to a log.
:again 
   set /p answer=Do you want to run a sql script (Y/N)?
   if /i "%answer:~,1%" EQU "Y" goto logit
   if /i "%answer:~,1%" EQU "N" exit /b
   echo Please type Y for Yes or N for No
   goto again
:logit
   echo sql script goes here. this command's response is sent to the log. >> test.log
   goto again
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.But I have already tried your suggestion .When I redirect parts of the script to a log file, the prompt for user input disappers

Comment: This solution is good but it not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: did it get you on the right track, to where you have a script that accepts input _and_ outputs to a log?